# Automatically add into aweber list

Tags: php, aweber

I created a registration form containing some personal details on users. What I want to do is once the form submitted and passed the validation, the name and email added automatically to aweber list.

Anyone can show some 'hint' how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **automatically subscribe mail** to aweber list, then here are some methods:

1) For example, if the list's name was BLABLA, someone could send an email to BLABLA@aweber.com to subscribe to the list.
 (You can change your autoresponder mail address by changing your list name at the "List Settings" page of your account.)

or

2) generate a form from your **aweber** account and copy & insert that script in a sample.php file. (form code is like:

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead."  >
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="853596399" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="chemiliti2" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou-coi.htm?m=text" 
AND ETC 
.........
.........
```

But find this place:

```
name="email" value=""
```

and for example, change to (you can use various variables to add mail automatically ... )

```
name="email" value="<?php echo $variab;?>"
```

then, after the end of the form, add this script:

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/JavaScript">document.forms[0].submit();</SCRIPT>
```

that's all. When the sample.php file is opened, it will do  request to entered mail (by $variab);

3) If wanted API for **automatic subscription**, see an example code:

```
https://labs.aweber.com/docs/create-subscribers
(based on POST Method, described here - https://labs.aweber.com/docs/reference/1.0#subscribers)
```

source: [aweber automatically subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686007/aweber-automatic-subscription)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the create POST method as described in here: in here: https://labs.aweber.com/docs/reference/1.0#subscribers

You can see a code sample here: https://labs.aweber.com/docs/create-subscribers